# How can I send a fetch() request through a proxy?

Tags: javascript, web

I have a HTTP proxy that I want to proxy all HTTP requests from my browser client app.

On the command line, I can proxy requests through this:

```
curl https://code.sgo.to --proxy localhost:5555
```

Or this:

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: "proxy",
  port: 8080,
  path: "http://www.google.com",
  headers: {
    Host: "www.google.com"
  }
};
http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  res.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

But, on the client, `path` doesn't seem like an actually valid `path`. E.g.

```
fetch("http://localhost:5555http://code.sgo.to")
```

Doesn't look right. But

```
fetch("http://localhost:5555/http://code.sgo.to")
```

Breaks my standard proxy because there is an extra `/` in the path that it is expecting to be passed an URL.

Would anyone know what's the equivalent of that in the browser (e.g. through `fetch()` or through `XMLHttpRequest`)?

Comment: Have you tried an encoded URL Path? http://localhost:5555/http%3A%2F%2Fcode.sgo.to

Answer (score -2):

Browsers don't allow you to do this.

Comment: If the proxy is setup to use/accept http requests and use the path of that request as the target for the proxy then it could be done this way. Hence why their http request in nodejs would work. For instance this is how cors proxy services work.

Comment: @PatrickEvans OP specifically asked about standard proxies, browsers and XMLHttpRequest / Fetch. The answer to this: it's just not possible. Of course you can swap out a technology and make it work, but that's not an answer to what was asked.